# I want a combination of 1,0 like 110,101,100,001,010,000 on my text box. If somebody types 140, there is an error. How can I write to proceed this?

Tags: vb.net, error-handling

```
    If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(bc.Text)) Then
        MsgBox("Please Insert something into the text box.")
    ElseIf Not Integer.TryParse(bc.Text, value) Then
        MsgBox("Please Insert number into the B.C text box")
```

These are my error checking codes to notify people who have typed string or numbers other than integers. In the bc.Text, I only want 3 length combination of 0 and 1 like 100,101,110, etc. If somebody types 150, I want msg box to say "Please insert an appropriate number into B.C box". How can I proceed this? Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter out your keypresses in the Textbox's `KeyDown` event using `SuppressKeyPress` to keep wrong value from showing in the Textbox.

This is a quick test of the concept:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
    If Not (e.KeyData = Keys.D1 Or e.KeyData = Keys.NumPad1 _
        Or e.KeyData = Keys.NumPad0 Or e.KeyData = Keys.D0 _
        Or e.KeyData = Keys.Back Or e.KeyData = Keys.Enter _
        Or e.KeyData = Keys.Delete) Then

        Beep()
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code makes a perfect sense. Idk why I tried to have if code to compare each value to 0,1. This is so much easier because user can't type other numbers. I have one more question tho. How about length control?

Comment: Use the `MaxLength` property of your TextBox

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Regular Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), like this:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

...

Dim rg As Regex = New Regex("^[01]{3}$")
Dim test As String = "111"
Dim b as Boolean = rg.IsMatch(test)
```

`b` will only be true if it matches any combinations of 3 1/0

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

A more primitive and probably performance inferior approach would be to first check the length and then use a string replace command to remove all "1" and "0" characters from the string, raising the message box if the resulting stripped string weren't empty.